# How to get access to a folder?

Tags: security, windows-7, permissions

I prohibited all types of access (full access, changing, reading writing) to the specified folder for the group "All Users". After that, even Built-In Admin can't access this folder.

Now I can't rollback those permission changes even from the account of Built-In Admin.

Comment: Are you trying to do this through API calls/programmatically, or just in general? If the latter, it may be better suited for SU.

Comment: I do in general.

Comment: You should not ask general questions here.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove ALL permissions to a file or folder you have to take ownership of it before you can do anything to it. Properties | Security | Advanced | Owner | Edit. I recommend that you login as Administrator and set owner to the “Administrators” group.  Then you can reset permissions.